# Need help improving a small C program

Tags: c, bash, shell, file-permissions, setuid

I wanted to launch a bash script (read: bash not sh script) as a root not as the user calling it, however bash ignore setuid on scripts, so I chose to write a very small script that takes a script/arguments and call it with setuid set.

This worked well and I went even further to verify that the script has setuid set on, executable and setuid() called on the owner of the file and not as root, to avoid any misuse of the program and I ended up with the program below..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char *command;
  int i, file_owner, size = 0;
  struct stat status_buf;
  ushort file_mode;

  // Check argc
  if (argc < 2) {
    printf("Usage: %s <script> [arguments]\n", argv[0]);
    return 1;
  }

  // Make sure the script does exist
  if(fopen(argv[1], "r") == NULL) {
    printf("The file %s does not exist.\n", argv[1]);
    return 1;
  }

  // Get the attributes of the file
  stat(argv[1], &status_buf);

  // Get the permissions of the file
  file_mode = status_buf.st_mode;

  // Make sure it's executable and it's setuid
  if(file_mode >> 6 != 567) {
    printf("The file %s should be executable and should have setuid set, please chmod it 0106755.\n", argv[1]);
    return 1;
  }

  // Get the owner of the script
  file_owner = status_buf.st_uid;

  // setuid
  setuid(file_owner);

  // Generate the command
  for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    size += strlen(argv[i]);
  }
  command = (char *) malloc( (size + argc + 11) * sizeof(char) );
  sprintf(command, "/bin/bash %s", argv[1]);
  if (argc > 2) {
    for (i = 2; i < argc; i++) {
      sprintf(command, "%s %s", command, argv[i]);
    }
  }

  // Execute the command
  system(command);

  // free memory
  free(command);

  return 0;
}
```

The exercise was not only to solve my problem, but it was also a way to get more into C, so what do you guys suggest? Is there anything I should improve ?

Thank you..

Comment: Sorry, this is not  a code review site.

Comment: ... http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is, though. Try there.

Comment: What is the exact difference of bash and sh script on a modern system? On most of the Linuxes sh is just a link/alias to bash.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I'll post the question there... Sorry again guys

Comment: @taskinoor: When invoked as `sh`, bash switches to "compatibility mode", which modifies some features and disables others.

Comment: I posted the same question on codereview http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2883/need-help-improving-a-small-c-program

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> if(file_mode >> 6 != 567) {
> ```

Magic numbers are bad. Use the `S_I*` bitmasks instead.

> ```
> system(command);
> ```

You're on *nix; use of `fork()` and `exec*()` will eliminate most of the acrobatics performed in the loop just before.

Comment: Hey Ignacio, could you please point me to any kind of documentation os the `S_I*` bitmasks ?

Comment: Never mind, I found it http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Permission-Bits.html#Permission-Bits